# How do I make an AJAX request from a firefox browser extension?

Tags: ajax, browser-extension

I'm totally new to browser extensions. I've had some success making a simple extension that automatically changes webpage content, and now I want it to change that content after querying the server for a true or false value. I'm trying to do this with an AJAX request (pure javascript). For some reason, I can't get any information out of the PHP script on the server with which my browser extension is interacting.

Manifest:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Truth Seeker",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "Returns true.",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/icon.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["script.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```

Script:

```
theBool = false;
url = /* PHP URL HERE */;
string = "";

request(MakeOutput, url, string);
if(theBool == true){
    alert("is true");
}

function MakeOutput(x){
    if(x == "true"){
       theBool = true; 
    }
}

function request(fix, url, string){         
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            fix(xhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(string);
}
```

The PHP file on the server just echos "true" at the moment. If I access that PHP script directly (by typing the URL into the browser), it will alert "is true". Why will it do it but no other pages will?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I tore my hair out on this for a while, gave up on myself, asked a question, and then figured the answer out on my own within a few more minutes. To help anyone else in the future, I added this to the manifest:

```
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
```

Comment: Perhaps things have changed, in a recent extension I used `httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();` with no specific `webRequest` permission in my manifest file, but rather the endpoint URL I wanted to access.